# How can I see Windows Device Manager changes?

Tags: windows, device-manager

When a new device (usually USB but not always) is added to a Windows machine, Windows adds that device as an entry in the Device Manager. You can even have the Device Manager open while device are plugged in to see the change happen. Unfortunately, it never looks like a "change". It always clears the list and then rebuilds it so changes can't be visually seen, either highlighted or simply noticing that the list shifted down.

Is there possibly some place in the Windows Event Viewer to see these device change events? Even better would be some notification bubble in the notification area, possibly provided by some 3rd party software. Does such software exist? I found EventGhost which does print some technical information when devices are added but doesn't seem to have the controls I'd like and is more intended for automation, not simply notifications.

For instance, when a serial port is added via some USB adapter, it would be very handy to just see something like "`Serial Device (COM8) added`" instead of searching the list of serial ports for which `COM#` was not in the list previously.

Another instance this would be handy is when devices behave badly and disconnect/reconnect regularly. Without such events, it's almost impossible to tell which device is acting up from the Device Manager view.

Comment: It should be recorded in event viewer somewhere, dig around in there.